# Harnack inequality for $F(D^{2}u, Du,x)=f$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I would like to know if there is an harnack inequality for the viscosity solutions of the following pde in the literature: $F(D^{2}u,Du,x)=f \in L^{\infty}(B_{1})$, for a function $u \in C(B_{1})$, and $F$ is uniformly elliptic in matricial entrie.
If so, where could you find it?